# Enable iPad Airplay on HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, ipad, prototype, html5-video, airplay

I'm doing this to enable Airplay on HTML5 video for my iPad 1st generation with iOS 4.3.1.

```
// Prototype JS framework
$('videoContainer').appendChild(
    new Element(
        'video', {
            id: 'video0',
            src: 'http://shapeshed.com/examples/HTML5-video-element/video/320x240.m4v',  
            controls: 'true',
            width: '200',
            height: '200',
        }
    )
);

$('video0').writeAttribute('x-webkit-airplay', 'allow');
```

When I turn on airplay, all I hear is audio on the TV. How do I enable video too?

**Edit:**

According to [Ben Dodson](http://bendodson.com/weblog/tag/airplay/), you have to re-embed the video. I did this:

```
$('videoContainer').update($('videoContainer').innerHTML);
```

Is there any way around this? Seems so hacky and it's wasted processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reformatting it as a .mp4 movie, and make sure that it is H.264 video with AAC audio. It has to be H.264, or the iPad can't steam it. (Got this from http://macosrumors.com/2011/01/12/first-look-mobile-safari-airplay/)

Comment: It was not an encoding issue. I got it to work with the same video. See my edit above.

Comment: Okay. Just wondering, do you have to embed it with Prototype? Or can you just flat out embed it with <video>, and skip the JS in the process. If you can, do something like this: `<video src="http://shapeshed.com/examples/HTML5-video-element/video/320x240.m4v" id="video0" width="200" height="200" x-webkit-airplay="allow"></video>`

Comment: Straight out writing to `innerHTML` also works, but it looks so ugly.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Then I'm sunk, haha. Sorry!

Comment: Whatever. This restriction is as stupid as iOS4 disabling autoplay. I'll just deal with crappy code.

Answer (score 0):

In old version of iOS maximum resolution supporting is 1024*576, However your resolution is normal. Please convert the video using any video converter to .mp4 or H.264. .m4v is not supporting format.